# shell command to obtain files from different folders

Tags: linux, shell

I have question related to obtaining files from different folders using shell command

I have the following directory name

```
TC1-T1
TC1-T2
TC1-T3
TC1-T4
```

I want to obtain the files from 1st directory (TC1-T1) , 2nd directory (TC1-T2), and then the loop goes to TC1-T3 (3rd) and 4th directory as (TC1-T4). I wrote the following code but it did not work. I am looking forward if someone can help me in editing the shell command.

```
for pair in "TC"{1..2}-"T"{1..10}; do for i  in $pair; do printf ${i}+1 printf "\n" done done
```

Comment: You are using the terms "folder" and "directory" inconsistently. Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: "Did not work" does not tell us much. Some of the respect in which this code could "not work" is just about leaving out mandatory whitespace (you need either a newline, a `;`, an `&`, or other command-separator syntax between statements).

Comment: (Also, if you add those missing command separators, `printf ${i}+1` is going to print something like `TC1-T1+1` -- that's _working_, insofar as it's the code doing exactly what it's written to do; if you meant to write the code to do something else, you'll need to be very explicit with us about what that something else is).

Comment: I should be using folder instead of directories. So currently I am trying to extract files from two different folder as TC1-T1, TC1-T2, and followed by TC1-T3 andTC1-T4. My question is how should I edit the loop to extract the following information.

Comment: What does `obtain the files from directory` mean. You want the names of all files under these directories?